# Explicit construction of $SO(3)$ elements from $SU(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $R \in SU(2)$ and let $\tau_a$ , $a=1,2,3$ be Pauli-Matrices (generators of $SU(2)$). I would like to show that the following matrix actually belongs to $SO(3)$. It is defined in components by:
$$O_{ab}:=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}(\tau_aR\tau_bR^{\dagger})$$
So I have to show that $OO^{T}=Id$ and that $\det(O)=1$. I started computing $OO^{T}$ in index notation, but ultimately failed to show it. Is there a nice way to show that $O \in SO(3)$?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $O O^T=Id$, one can use that (Einstein summation convention used)
$$ \tau^a_{ij}\tau^a_{kl}=2\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}-\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}.$$
Here $a,b,c$ represents the $SO(3)$ indices, while $i,j,k,l$ represents the "internal" $SU(2)$ indices (i.e. $\tau^3_{ij}=\delta_{ij}(\delta_{i1}-\delta_{i2})$ and so on).
After some calculation, one gets
$$O_{ab}O_{ac}=\frac12 {\rm Tr}( \tau^a\tau^c)-\frac14 {\rm Tr}( \tau^a) {\rm Tr}(\tau^c)=\delta_{bc},$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, it's still not entirely clear to me: By "internal" $SU(2)$ indices do you mean the matrix indices of the Pauli-Matrices (so $i,j,k,l=1,2$)? And also, $O_{ab}O_{ac}$ (or, in other words $(O^TO)_{bc}$ should be equal to $\delta_{bc}$ or not? Could you perhaps specify your calculations a bit and especially the way in which you use the relation mentioned in your answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes and yes. Sorry, there were some typos in my answer, that I have corrected.